# Deploy local repo to Docker container without building image

Tags: docker

Is there anyway for me to deploy a local repository to a docker container sitting on a remote server without doing `docker build`? My workflow is setting up the environment inside of a docker container so that I'll be able to push to that container, inside of a remote server, via Mina(Rails).

Fairly new to Docker and the only things I see is turning your app into an image and deploying using the Dockerfile. Any advice or links to articles would be greatly appreciated! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a prebuilt image, just `docker run` and attach your self to that container then run whatever executables you want ( or deploy inside that docker container ),

If you need some preinstalled packages inside that image then you can check the the [docker hub](https://registry.hub.docker.com/), if none match your exact needs, you can create your own docker file and let docker build that image for you, then you can use `docker pull` that image to your server and just run the executables you want inside that image.

Comment: Thanks @Mohammad AbuShady! I guess the part that is confusing to me is   deploying to that prebuilt container, locally.  Deploying to the server is fairly straight forward. It's getting my app from my local machine, to, inside of the prebuilt container, inside of the server that is the tricky part (without installing git and cloning directly into it mind you).  Is this possible?

Comment: you won't install git on the server, but in the image, like install all the dependencies, but not the code it self, then you can add a script inside the image that clones the code and runs it.

Comment: you can also use docker volumes, or mount folders inside the container http://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/ to maintain the code state between containers, that way even if you update the image and create a new container from the new image, the code state is still preserved and you can remount them in the new containers, a good example for this is the mysql image for example, keeping the database files on the host machine such that if you update the mysql version ( by updating the image ) you won't loose your data

Answer (score 0):

expose another port on the run command(i.e -p 2201:22). install ssh into running, prebuilt container and deploy mina to that port so that it will forward to that container.